# When to use \nolimits when defining a math operator?

Tags: math-operators, plain-tex

In plain TeX, `\cos` is defined as `\mathop {\rm cos}\nolimits` but `\gcd` as `\mathop {\rm gcd}`.

In what case to use `\nolimits` when defining a math operator to be typeset in roman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not a TeX question, but a math one. Anyway, this is the list in `plain.tex`:

```
\def\log{\mathop{\rm log}\nolimits}
\def\lg{\mathop{\rm lg}\nolimits}
\def\ln{\mathop{\rm ln}\nolimits}
\def\lim{\mathop{\rm lim}}
\def\limsup{\mathop{\rm lim\,sup}}
\def\liminf{\mathop{\rm lim\,inf}}
\def\sin{\mathop{\rm sin}\nolimits}
\def\arcsin{\mathop{\rm arcsin}\nolimits}
\def\sinh{\mathop{\rm sinh}\nolimits}
\def\cos{\mathop{\rm cos}\nolimits}
\def\arccos{\mathop{\rm arccos}\nolimits}
\def\cosh{\mathop{\rm cosh}\nolimits}
\def\tan{\mathop{\rm tan}\nolimits}
\def\arctan{\mathop{\rm arctan}\nolimits}
\def\tanh{\mathop{\rm tanh}\nolimits}
\def\cot{\mathop{\rm cot}\nolimits}
\def\coth{\mathop{\rm coth}\nolimits}
\def\sec{\mathop{\rm sec}\nolimits}
\def\csc{\mathop{\rm csc}\nolimits}
\def\max{\mathop{\rm max}}
\def\min{\mathop{\rm min}}
\def\sup{\mathop{\rm sup}}
\def\inf{\mathop{\rm inf}}
\def\arg{\mathop{\rm arg}\nolimits}
\def\ker{\mathop{\rm ker}\nolimits}
\def\dim{\mathop{\rm dim}\nolimits}
\def\hom{\mathop{\rm hom}\nolimits}
\def\det{\mathop{\rm det}}
\def\exp{\mathop{\rm exp}\nolimits}
\def\Pr{\mathop{\rm Pr}}
\def\gcd{\mathop{\rm gcd}}
\def\deg{\mathop{\rm deg}\nolimits}
```

and you can see that `\nolimits` is for symbols of function taking a fixed number of arguments (mostly one, but `\hom` takes two), whereas `\limits` is for functions with any number of arguments (or whose standard argument is a set).

Exception: the limit related symbols (which originated the others not taking `\nolimits`).

Answer (score 11):

Trig functions are often used with superscripts

[image]

You can see why `\nolimits` are needed as you don't want limits

```
$$ \mathop{\rm cos}^2  + \mathop{\rm cos}^2  = 1$$

$$ \mathop{\rm cos}\nolimits^2  + \mathop{\rm cos}\nolimits^2  = 1$$

\bye
```

Comment: er I think one of those cos ought to be sin :-)

Comment: If you fixed it, you could also add $$\max_{x \in I} f(x)$$.

Comment: Will `\operatorname` save us having to introduce `\nolimits`?

Comment: @hesham I don't understand the question, you almost never need `\nolimits` in a document `\cos` is defined to use `\nolimits`,  `\operatorname` is just an amsmath macro that defines commands using `\mathop` and optionally with `\nolimits` so it is the same as shown here.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks, that is what I needed to make sure of. That is, if we used `\operatorname` with amsmath , in that case we don't need to worry about adding `\nolimits` to display the square power properly.

Comment: @hesham you wouldn't normally  use `\operatorname` either, normally you would declare a command like \cos using `\DeclareMathOperator` but in either case you have the same choice `\operatorname*` or `\operatorname` with the star form controlling whether `\nolimits` is used.

Answer (score 6):

Use `\nolimits` when you do not want superscripts and subscripts to appear above and below the operator in display mode, the way they do for `\lim`, `\sum` or `\int`.  An example is `\cos^2 t`, which should display as cos² *t*, and not with a 2 above the letter o.